# Else in webscraping: div[2] else div[3]

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

I'm trying to fetch info from a website with chrome driver.

I'd like to get something that sometimes appears as

/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/**span[3]**

and other times as

/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/**span[2]**

**How can I include an else in webscraping?** If span[3] doesn't return anything, try span[2]

Answer (score 2):

you could make use of 'try' and 'except' like below :

```
try:
    driver.find_element(By.XPATH, '/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/span[3]')
    'do something'
except:
    try:
        driver.find_element(By.XPATH,'/html/body/div[1]/div/div/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[4]/div[2]/span[2]')
        'do something'
    except:
        pass
```

it will go to first try to find span3 , and if there is no span3 it will try to find span2.

if both element are not there then it should continue.
..